# Extract POIs of specific area from OSM file

Tags: gratis, xml, openstreetmap, wikivoyage

I have [an OSM file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-OSM/) that contains POIs (Points Of Interest) all over the world.

I want to create a new OSM file that would contain only the POIs that are in a particular area.

Being able to select an area by drawing would be wonderful, but I am OK with a rectangle too. Can be command line or GUI.

Free.

Comment: How did you generate that OSM file? I've downloaded the latest version (_enwikivoyage-20150220-listings.osm_) from [DataHub](http://datahub.io/dataset/wikivoyage-listings-as-osm) and tried to import it in [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) to see what I could do with it, but I got this error first  _"Unsupported version: 0.5 (at line 2, column 47)."_. After amending the version to something newer like _0.6_ as suggested [somewhere](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/11239), I got another error _"Missing attribute 'version' on OSM primitive with ID 1. (at line 3, column 58)._".

Comment: @mguassa: Thanks for the feedback, I just fixed the version problem so the next release will hopefully be OK! https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/wikivoyage2osm/commit/937bd53f163582db2cff006f253d4bcf1b6c14b2